# Retrieve a date from sqlite database in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I've used the following code to create a database

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBclass extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static final String DB_NAME="Camera";
private static final String TABLE_NAME="Cam";

public DBclass(Context context)
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
}
//table creation
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_NAME +
            " (date Number, time Number, comments Varchar,image blob);");
}
}
```

and this function to save data:

```
public void store(View view)
{
    byte[] img=bitmapToByte(photo);
    String DATE,TIME,COMMENTS;
    DATE=date.getText().toString();
    TIME=time.getText().toString();
    COMMENTS=comments.getText().toString();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("date",DATE);
    values.put("time",TIME);
    values.put("comments",COMMENTS);
    values.put("image",img);

    test.getWritableDatabase();
    test.getWritableDatabase().insert("cam", "date", values);
}
```

and this for retrieval

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
List<String> commentList = new ArrayList<String>();
DBclass db=new DBclass(getApplicationContext());
Cursor cursor;

cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT comments FROM Cam WHERE date = ?", new String(date));

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
                        commentList.add(cursor.getString(0));
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }

                comm.setText(commentList.toString());
            }
```

Saving of data is done. The current system date is saved in the "date" column. The requirement is to retrieve the "date" from the database check if it is equal to system date and if yes display the corresponding "comments" in a Textview.

How to retrieve "date" from the database?

Comment: I am begining to learn android...please help

Comment: now compiler could not resolve the rawQuery method...please do help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String getAllCommentsByDate(long date){
    List<String> commentList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT comments FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE date = " + String.valueOf(date);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            commentList.add(cursor.getString(0))
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return commentList;
}
```

I dont know in which format your date is. So this example uses a long value for a specific datetime. You should properly modify this on your needs.

Comment: I am trying your logic but a small problem.The compiler cannot resolve the db.rawQuery method.What may be the factor ? Ive created the db object for my Database class and called the getWritableDatabase method too

Comment: Could you provide some more information about the error? For me this works well. This method should be inside a class which extends from SqliteOpenHelper and the rawQuery method come from an SqliteDatabase object.

Comment: "cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT comments FROM Cam WHERE date = ?", new String(date)); "        This is the error statement. db is an object of database class which has SqliteOpenHelper imported. Error states "cannot resolve method rawQuery"

Comment: I've tried the second argument of rawQuery to be null like in ur code. That too dint work.

Comment: I've found something. I could not make a call to other functions like execSQL(). However i could call getWritableDatabase. What could be the problem ? Please help

Comment: If you want to use the second parameter of rawQuery then you have to pass a String Array to it: "cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT comments FROM Cam WHERE date = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(date)}); "

Comment: Ya that is okay.But still the rawQuery method cannot be resolved

Comment: Could you edit your initial post with your entire Class? I need to have a closer view. Maybe i can figure out why this happens.